# Postgresql: how to copy a column from a table to another using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using `psycopg2` in `python` to manage my database.

I created two tables. One called `data` that I want to populate with some data. For doing so I created a temporary table called `temporarytable` from a `.csv` file.

I want to copy the column `numberofinhabitants`. So what I am doing is the following:

```
### Add Column
import psycopg2 as ps    
stat1 = """  ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN numberofinhabitants integer"""
con = ps.connect(dbname = 'mydb', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='mypd')
con.autocommit = True
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(stat1)
cur.close()
con.close()


### Copy Column
stat2 = """INSERT INTO data (numberofinhabitants) SELECT numberofinhabitants FROM temporarytable"""
con = ps.connect(dbname = 'mydb', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='mypd')
con.autocommit = True
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(stat2)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

but I get the following error

```
ProgrammingError: column "numberofinhabitants" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO data (numberofinhabitants) SELECT numberofinhabi...
                                                      ^
HINT:  There is a column named "numberofinhabitants" in table "data", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Below a screenshot from `pgAdmin3` after `SELECT * FROM temporarytable;`

[image]

Comment: Where are you creating `temporarytable`? Can't it be that the table, being temporary, is already deleted by the time you try to copy?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't close the connection and reopen it (that may remove the temp table) or you should create a regular table.

Comment: @franciscosollima it is a regular table that I called `temporarytable`

Comment: Oh nevermind then

Comment: Can you show the output of `SELECT * FROM temporarytable`?

Comment: @franciscosollima I added a screenshot from `pgadmin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that PostgreSQL's columns are **case sensitive**. You should try this as stat2:

```
stat2 = """INSERT INTO data (numberofinhabitants) SELECT "numberOfInhabitants" FROM temporarytable"""
```

Note that you should also use `"` for columns with upper characters in them.